# assign custom pubic domain name for WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have my WSO2 API Manager set up in EC2. I have bought a custom domain name from route 53 and now thats pointing to this EC2 instance.
How can I assign custom domain name for WSO2? 
I have heard of the reverse proxy ;But i could not understand it..Can someone explain it?is there any other alternate solutions?
Will the WSO2 start in a domain name? 
Whats the best way to achieve this?

How can i make SSL work in this case? I bought a SSL certificate for the domain as well.. How can i make the certificate work with in EC2 with this domain name?

Thnak You

Answer (score 0):

You bought a custom domain name, let's say `mycustomdomain.com` and configured Route 53 to point to it.

If you didn't change the default ports you should be able to access `mycustomdomain.com:9443/store` normally

If you can't connect, try to change Security Group rules to allow inbound traffic from port 9443 in your EC2 instance.

Comment: But will SSL work in this case? I bought a SSL certificate for the domain as well.. How can i make the certificate work with in EC2 with this domain name?
I have edited the question to add this point